# Why is the "FILE" data type in C not simply written as "file"?

Tags: c, file, types, compiler-construction

I'm curious as to why this specific data type is written in all caps. What was the reasoning behind this? Is it a consequence of the compiler's implementation or a data type conflict or something along those lines?

Comment: Because C is case sensitive! :)

Comment: +1, I would have expected `file_t` or something along those lines.

Comment: For those who are able to see the deleted answers, `FILE` is *not* a macro. (It may have been one historically, before `typedef` was added to the language, and that might explain the all-caps name.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: but then an equally valid answer would be that it was named before the "all caps = Macros only" rule :)

Comment: @Jongware: I don't think so. I'm fairly sure the name `FILE` predates the invention of typedefs, so it must have been a macro originally. I'm not sure how far back the convention of using all-caps for macro names goes, but surely that's answerable.

Comment: @KeithThompson: just checked K&R, 2nd ed. (1978/1988). §4.11.2 contains a couple of examples of macros in lowercase, and any relevance of case is not mentioned.

Comment: @Jongware: Yes, that's curious. But just because one book, even K&R2, doesn't follow a convention doesn't mean it didn't exist then.

Comment: @KeithHommpson: yes, [it was a #define](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/include/stdio.h) in the Old Days.  Typedefs did exist in the V7 days, but they were relatively new, and stdio goes back to PWB/UNIX and "Phototypesetter, Seventh Edition", and typedef might have been very new features back then.